# Better Method to Plot a Series of Bar Charts in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 4x3 bar charts which I save as figures then I combine them in one image after that in latex. The problem is that the barcharts are two small, and I'm wondering if there is any Matlab type of figure that would be better on showing my results. Also I'm wondering if there is a way to save it as a one figure in Matlab so that I don't have to combine them in latex?

This is an example on how it looks like in latex:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a sample of a chart you're making? Have you tried multibar charts? Also, are your charts a percentage of a whole or what kind of data are you showing?

Comment: @krisdestruction I edited my question showing how my barchart looks like.  yes, each bar is a percentage. I have two bars (yellow, blue) so as shown there are `21x2` (21 blue and 21 yellow). And I have 4x3 of them where each row (5) represents different `conditions` and each column (3) represents different `scenario`, so there are three different `scenarios` for each `condition`.

Comment: So the way to plot multiple plots in a single figure is `subplot`. I'm just thinking of a better way to display the data though. What if you use `imagesc` and show your results with a colormap instead? I've done that for past papers and it seemed to work well. Then if you need to reference a specific number, you can point them to tables in the appendicies. Thoughts?

Comment: mmm, could you show me how to do so and how it looks like? so that I understand what you mean please? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to do a scatter plot of the 3 trials and 2 scenarios and combine each row of plots into 1 plot. Let me write up an answer

Comment: Check my answer out, let me know if you need more detail. I would show you the `imagesc` method, but it requires a colorbar and color map that I don't think would look good in a paper if you're just comparing methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can easily combine the scenario and trials using a scatter plot. Suppose each column in your bar was labelled a, b, and c. Then if you have the following data:

```
a = [90 95 98]';
b = [20 25 29]';
c = [50 40 30]';
```

You can create an index matrix labelling which column it should go into.

```
t = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]';
```

Then create the scatter plot with `*` markers. You can even use different different [colors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) or [markers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) built into Matlab to denote different trials/conditions/methods/input.

```
scatter(t,[a; b; c], '*');
```

You can then set the labels as follows.

```
set(gca,'Xtick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'})
```

Here is the resultant plot.

[image]